# HTML Form with "Generate(Random Characters)" and then "Finalize(insert to database)" later

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I would like to ask for your suggestion or better if you have. This is the problem in my website. I am not expert in AJAX and/or Javascript. Here is the scenario:

In my modal, there is a form that have two inputs:

**1. Number of string(randomized) to generate**

**2. A string that will appear in every data(randomized string) that will be generated. (This can be null)**

---

For demonstration, I input "5" in the first parameter. Then "sample" to the second. And clicked the **"Generate" button**.

Now, the 5 strings with "sample" in every generated data will load in the same modal.

---

After the strings are shown. I will click the **"Finalize" button** then the generated strings will be inserted to my database.

Is this possible? Or should I look for a work-around?

---

**modalAndform.php:**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-generate-string">
  Generate Strings 
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-generate-string">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url("mycontroller/generate"); ?>>
            <!--- inputs --->
            Quantity: <input type="number" name="quantity" required><br/>
            Custom Prefix(optional): <input type="text" name="prefix">
            <button type="submit">Generate</button>

            <div class="for_the_result"></div>

            <!--- submit/close modal --->        
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button">Insert Strings</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**mycontroller.php**

```
function generate(){
  $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
  $prefix = $this->input->post('prefix');

  $myArray = array();
  while($quantity){
    $string1 = mdt(time());
    $string2 = $string1.$prefix;
    array_push($myArray, $string2);
    $quantity--;
  }

  //I dont have any idea what to do after this. All of data in $myArray should be display back to "modalAndform.php" <div class="for_the_result"></div>;
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding your code to your question, that would help a lot to understand the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Minnen. I already updated my question and added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to treat this problem, here I will leave an example.
In relation to recording in the database it is also possible ... we could do it with ajax. But then we would have to see how your backend is doing to receive this information :)

> Obs:In the code, the value of the variable position is 3. This means that it will insert the standard string after 3 characters. If you want the default string to enter another position, just change that value.

```js
$("#generate").on("click", function(){
  var defaultString = $("#defaultString").val();
  var numberOfStrings = $("#numberOfStrings").val();
  for( var i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++){
     var stringGenerated = generateString(defaultString);
     $("#results").append(stringGenerated + "</br>");
  } 
});

function generateString(defaultString){
     var random           = '';
     var characters      =                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
     var charactersLength = characters.length;
     for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      random += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *        charactersLength));
   }
   var position = 3;
   var output = [random.slice(0, position), defaultString, random.slice(position)].join('');
   return output;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Number of strings</span>
<input id="numberOfStrings" type="number" />
<hr>
<span>Default string</span>
<input id="defaultString" type="text" />
</br></br>
<button id="generate">GENERATE STRINGS</button>
</br>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<span id="results">

</span>
```

Comment: Hello Tom. I updated my question. I added my codes in form and my process.

As what I understand to your response: 

My first step is to generate the strings using javascript, not using <form>?
After that, it will return the generated strings to the <form>?
And this is the database part goes in?

Comment: I believe it is better to generate the string in the frontend (with javascript / jquery) to display the results to the user in the modal and then send the data to the backend (codeigniter) to register the strings. With your code I now understand better. I'm setting up an example of how it would work

Comment: Hello Tom. I will flag this answer. Since, my program is now running. And thanks to this, because I used this solution. Thank you.